# Android .dcm file association

Tags: android, file, view, load, dicom

Does anyone know an Application which opens a dcm file when it is clicked on in say a file manager? I need to be able to load a dcm from a http url into an app that displays a dicom image.

Answer (score 0):

I found one app with name **Droid Dicom Viewer** in some posts about .DCM file.

I found this link to get details about Droid Dicom Viewer.

[ADIView - Android DICOM Image Viewer](https://sites.google.com/site/adiview/)

Comment: droid sometimes refer to android. But it may refer to android version in some smart phones like HTC Droid Eris, Motorola Droid, Samsung Droid Charge, etc.

Comment: droid has the open issue still it not resolved yet.if any other then let me know.:)